# Parse between Double and String with variable decimal places

Tags: vb.net, string, file, parsing, double

I have a directory full of txt-files. The amount of files is variable. The names of the files are like these:

...
0,7.txt
0,8.txt
0,85.txt
1,0.txt
1,1.txt
...

The name of any file is important for my calculations in the code.

```
   'Freifahrtdiagramm einlesen
        Public Shared fortschrittsziffer As New List(Of Double)
        Public Shared schubbeiwert As New List(Of Double)
        Shared Sub freifahrtdiagrammEinlesen(dateiname As String)
            fortschrittsziffer.Clear()
            schubbeiwert.Clear()
            Dim datei As New FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\Freifahrtdiagramm\" + dateiname, FileMode.Open)
            Dim leser As New StreamReader(datei)
            Dim zeile As String
            Dim werte() As String

            While leser.Peek <> -1
                zeile = leser.ReadLine
                werte = zeile.Split(";")
                fortschrittsziffer.Add(werte(0))
                schubbeiwert.Add(werte(1))
            End While
            leser.Close()
            datei.Close()
        End Sub

        'kT aus einer vorhandenen Datei auslesen
        Shared Function kTAusDateiLesen(J As Double, PD As Double) As Double
            Dim J0 As Double
            Dim J1 As Double
            Dim kT0 As Double
            Dim kT1 As Double
            freifahrtdiagrammEinlesen(PD.ToString + ".txt")
            For i = 0 To fortschrittsziffer.Count - 1
                If fortschrittsziffer.Item(i) >= J Then
                    If i = 0 Then
                        J0 = 0
                        kT0 = 0
                    Else
                        J0 = fortschrittsziffer.Item(i - 1)
                        kT0 = schubbeiwert.Item(i - 1)
                    End If
                    J1 = fortschrittsziffer.Item(i)
                    kT1 = schubbeiwert.Item(i)
                    If J1 - J0 = 0 Then
                        kTAusDateiLesen = 0
                    Else
                        kTAusDateiLesen = kT0 + (kT1 - kT0) / (J1 - J0) * (J - J0)
                    End If
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next
            kTAusDateiLesen = 0
        End Function   



'kT bestimmen. Wenn Datei nicht vorhanden, dann interpolieren
        Shared Function kTBestimmen(J As Double, PD As Double) As Double
            If System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\Freifahrtdiagramm\" + PD.ToString + ".txt") Then
                kTBestimmen = kTAusDateiLesen(J, PD)
            Else
                Dim ordner As New DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath + "\Freifahrtdiagramm\")
                Dim wert1 As Double = 0
                Dim wert2 As Double = 0
                For Each datei As FileInfo In ordner.GetFiles
                    If Double.Parse(Replace(datei.Name, ".txt", "")) > PD Then
                        wert2 = kTAusDateiLesen(J, Double.Parse(Replace(datei.Name, ".txt", "")))
                        kTBestimmen = (wert1 + wert2) / 2
                        Exit Function
                    Else
                        wert1 = kTAusDateiLesen(J, Double.Parse(Replace(datei.Name, ".txt", "")))
                    End If
                Next
                kTBestimmen = 0
            End If
        End Function
```

If I call my function kTBestimmen() with a PD and the file PD.txt exists, there is no problem at all. If the PD.txt does not exist, then i want to open the two files inbetween the PD is. So if my PD in kTBestimmen is 1,25, and 1,25.txt does not exist, I want to open 1,2.txt and 1,3.txt.

To find these two files, the bigger one and the smaller one, I tried to parse my filenamestring to a double. I replace ".txt" as "" and then parse it to Double. But the parse changes 1,0 to 1 which gives me an error, because only the file 1,0.txt exists and not 1.txt. I could my format my double to always have one decimal place but that won't work with other filenames like 0,85.txt.

Do you have a solution for my problem? Or can you give me some ideas to solve my problem different?

Comment: How about to add extra 0s for making variable decimal point to fixed decimal point(0,7.txt -> 0,700.txt, 1,0.txt -> 1,000.txt , and so on), then remove comma and ".txt" , and parse each data as integer.

Comment: You have to specify the number of decimal when converting from a double to a string: value.ToString("n1")

Comment: ToString("n1") was excatly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed my files so that they always have two decimal points:

...
 0,70.txt
 0,80.txt
 0,85.txt
 1,00.txt
 1,10.txt
...

By using value.toString("nx") you force the parse to use x decimal points. So if value = 1 I would get a string "1,00" by parsing with value.toString("n2"). That solves the problem.